# QWebview, HTTP proxy, html5 video does not work

Tags: proxy, html5-video, qtwebkit, qwebview

I'm using QWebView to show chat log.

```
webView = new QWebView(this);
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrivateBrowsingEnabled, true);
webView->settings()->setMaximumPagesInCache(0);
webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);
```

If the proxy for QWebView is not set the HTML code like this works fine.

```
<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + rxYouTube.cap(11) + "\" ></iframe>
```

But when I do something like this

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
proxy.setHostName("_ip_");
proxy.setPort(_port_);
proxy.setUser("_login_");
proxy.setPassword("_passsword_");
QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

YouTube tells me that my browser does not supports HTML5.

How I can solve this problem?

PS Platform: Qt 4.8, Windows, VC

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested going through a proxy yet, although my LAN uses a transparent auto-proxy so at least that much works, but I have worked out how to get general HTML5 Video support in a QWebView on Windows.  I've written a blog post about that you can read here: http://blog.enthought.com/open-source/fun-with-qtwebkit-html5-video/  It involves building Qt + qt-mobility, and also a bug fix in qt-mobility.